# jQuery selector returns duplicate elements in Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery selector that queries elements by tag name and class.  In a query that I'd expect to return three elements, Safari (v3.1.1 for Windows) returns an extra element.

The cause seems to be the numeric ID*.  Changing the ID to a non-numeric eliminates the duplicate element.  Strangely, changing the ID of the first element to other numbers has a seemingly-random effect on the final result count.  An ID of 4 increases the result count to five.  0, 9, and 1234 all return four elements.

```
<div class="mydiv" id="1"></div>
<div class="mydiv" id="2"></div>
<div class="mydiv" id="3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var div = $('div.mydiv');
        alert( div.length );                // Safari 3.1.1 returns 4
        alert( $.unique( div ).length );    // Safari 3.1.1 returns 3
    } );
</script>
```

Firefox 3 and IE 7 display 3 in both alert boxes.

`*` I know that numeric IDs [are not valid HTML identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html).  <strike>The jqGrid plugin I'm using uses numbers for row IDs by default.</strike>  I'll look into changing this behavior, but in the meantime I'm curious why this is affecting the above query.

### EDIT

It's been a while since I looked at my data retrieval code for jqGrid.  It turns out that I can set row IDs to be whatever I want on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **You will always get unpredictable behavior when using invalid HTML.**  *(Even if what you're doing works 95% of the time)*

The issue is just as you stated, numerical IDs aren't valid, so when doing counts, etc, the browser is free to make this assumption...if they are invalid and it causes a bug, well...it's not their bug.

Comment: +1 because I agree with the sentiment of your answer. However in practice browser hacks are something we have to live with daily.